# use circuitikz picture inside tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

In block scheme I like to add  a node with call out shape, which contain details of electronic circuit. This electronic circuit is easy to draw with circutikz package. Here is my attempt to achieve this goal:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,%
                    shapes,shapes.callouts%
                    }
    \usepackage{fouriernc}
    \usepackage[scaled=0.83]{helvet}
    \usepackage[scaled=0.82]{luximono}
    \usepackage{marvosym,pifont}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[european,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-family,
     color = teal!40!black}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (4,0);
\draw (1,-0.1) -- (1,0.1);
\draw (2,-0.1) -- (2,0.1);
\draw (3,-0.1) -- (3,0.1);
    \draw[ultra thick,*-*] (a) -- (b);
\node[shape=rectangle callout,
      draw, rounded corners,
      callout pointer width=3.3 mm,
      callout pointer shorten=-2mm,
      font=\sffamily\footnotesize,
      align=center,
      callout absolute pointer={(b)},
      scale=0.5] at ([xshift=19mm,yshift=3mm] b)
    {termination circuit\\
    \begin{circuitikz}[sharp corners]
\draw[ultra thick, blue] plot[smooth,domain=-0.25*pi:-0.75*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{-1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw[ultra thick, red]  plot[smooth,domain=-0.25*pi:-0.75*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{+1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw[ultra thick, red]  plot[smooth,domain=-0.75*pi:-1.25*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{+1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw[ultra thick, blue] plot[smooth,domain=-0.75*pi:-1.25*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{-1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw   (0,3)   node[right] {\SI{+5}{V}}
    to [R=$R_s$,o-] (0,+1)  node[right] {A}
    to [R=$R_k$,*-*] (0,-1) node[right] {B}
    to [R=$R_s$, -o] (0,-3)
                node[right] {\SI{0}{V}};
    \end{circuitikz}
    };
\node[shape=rectangle callout,
      draw, rounded corners,
      callout pointer width=3.3 mm, 
      callout pointer shorten=-2mm,
      font=\sffamily\footnotesize, 
      align=center,
      callout absolute pointer={(a)},
      scale=0.5] at ([xshift=-19mm,yshift=3mm] a)
    {termination circuit\\
    \begin{circuitikz}[sharp corners]
\draw[ultra thick, blue] plot[smooth,domain=-0.25*pi:-0.75*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{-1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw[ultra thick, red]  plot[smooth,domain=-0.25*pi:-0.75*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{+1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw[ultra thick, red]  plot[smooth,domain=-0.75*pi:-1.25*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{+1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw[ultra thick, blue] plot[smooth,domain=-0.75*pi:-1.25*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{-1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw   (0,3)   node[right] {\SI{+5}{V}}
    to [R=$R_s$,o-] (0,+1)  node[right] {A}
    to [R=$R_k$,*-*] (0,-1) node[right] {B}
    to [R=$R_s$, -o] (0,-3)
                node[right] {\SI{0}{V}};
    \end{circuitikz}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Questions:

- why both nodes are not the same (as I expected);
- why I receive error "unknown function 'south (in south east)' if I use for positioning of node possibilities offered by `positioning` library?

  \node[shape=rectangle callout,
    draw, rounded corners,
    callout pointer width=3.3 mm, 
    callout pointer shorten=-2mm,
    font=\sffamily\footnotesize, 
    align=center,
    callout absolute pointer={(a)},
    scale=0.5,
    above left=-19mm and 3mm of a] {content of node};

[image]

Edit: I correct a bit my preamble where by mistake I had \usepackage{circuitikz} twice. The second one should be `siunitx` wit added setup. I like to have labels of resistors in sans sheriff font, but this hasn't happen. I do not knoe why not, but this is not a issue of this questionseparate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `circuitikz` inside a node. The `circuitikz` environment is nothing but a `tikzpicture` environment in disguise. Using `tikzpicture` inside a `node` is not a good idea and it will cause odd things. You can use a `box` instead. I have created `\mycircuita` and `\mycircuitb` boxes (with 0 and 20V) and used them inside the callout node.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,%
                    shapes,shapes.callouts%
                    }
    \usepackage{fouriernc}
    \usepackage[scaled=0.83]{helvet}
    \usepackage[scaled=0.82]{luximono}
    \usepackage{marvosym,pifont}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[european,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\newsavebox{\mycircuita}
\sbox{\mycircuita}{%
\begin{circuitikz}[sharp corners]
\draw[ultra thick, blue] plot[smooth,domain=-0.25*pi:-0.75*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{-1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw[ultra thick, red]  plot[smooth,domain=-0.25*pi:-0.75*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{+1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw[ultra thick, red]  plot[smooth,domain=-0.75*pi:-1.25*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{+1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw[ultra thick, blue] plot[smooth,domain=-0.75*pi:-1.25*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{-1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw   (0,3)   node[right] {\SI{+5}{V}}
    to [R=$R_s$,o-] (0,+1)  node[right] {A}
    to [R=$R_k$,*-*] (0,-1) node[right] {B}
    to [R=$R_s$, -o] (0,-3)
                node[right] {\SI{0}{V}};
    \end{circuitikz}
    }
\newsavebox{\mycircuitb}
\sbox{\mycircuitb}{%
\begin{circuitikz}[sharp corners]
\draw[ultra thick, blue] plot[smooth,domain=-0.25*pi:-0.75*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{-1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw[ultra thick, red]  plot[smooth,domain=-0.25*pi:-0.75*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{+1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw[ultra thick, red]  plot[smooth,domain=-0.75*pi:-1.25*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{+1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw[ultra thick, blue] plot[smooth,domain=-0.75*pi:-1.25*pi, samples=36] (0.25*pi+\x,{-1*sin(2*\x r)});
\draw   (0,3)   node[right] {\SI{+5}{V}}
    to [R=$R_s$,o-] (0,+1)  node[right] {A}
    to [R=$R_k$,*-*] (0,-1) node[right] {B}
    to [R=$R_s$, -o] (0,-3)
                node[right] {\SI{20}{V}};
    \end{circuitikz}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (4,0);
\draw (1,-0.1) -- (1,0.1);
\draw (2,-0.1) -- (2,0.1);
\draw (3,-0.1) -- (3,0.1);
    \draw[ultra thick,*-*] (a) -- (b);
\node[shape=rectangle callout,
      draw, rounded corners,
      callout pointer width=3.3 mm,
      callout pointer shorten=-2mm,
      font=\sffamily\footnotesize,
      align=center,
      callout absolute pointer={(b)},
      scale=0.5] at ([xshift=19mm,yshift=3mm] b)
    {termination circuit\\
\usebox{\mycircuita}
    };
\node[shape=rectangle callout,
      draw, rounded corners,
      callout pointer width=3.3 mm,
      callout pointer shorten=-2mm,
      font=\sffamily\footnotesize,
      align=center,
      callout absolute pointer={(a)},
      scale=0.5] at ([xshift=-19mm,yshift=3mm] a)
    {termination circuit\\
    \usebox{\mycircuitb}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

As an alternative, you could also use `pic` facility of `tikz` but using a `box` is simpler in this case.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for fast response. Your solution solve most of the my problems, but I wonder it is possible to define content of \mycircuit locally, somewhere at tikzpicture (inside or till before)? I like to use this savebox for more similar cases in other tikz figures and like to have their definitions of content locally at the tikpictures.

Comment: Harish Kumar, yes, I can do this, but I have all my picture saved in different folders ... in picture are included in document which also included in main document: So I afraid that I will have problems with the paths (images is from my textbook). I need to think about how to organize and save those boxes.

Comment: I'm familiar with namening of boxes, zhis not make me problems :-). Now I found temporary solution how to manage problem of storing this boxes. I can have them as part of standalon figure and inclede generated pdf file with \includegraphics instead to include it directly with \input and compile it again with document or main document.

Comment: @Zarko That is always an option. But then you have to be careful about the size of figures included ;)