# Use in TikZ a shape from Circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib

In the `circuitikz` package a specific element called `sinusoidal voltage source` is available (it is presented in the [manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf), page 18, first image).

The code (or part of it) is in the `tex/pgfcircbipoles.tex` inside the package. I tried to use it in a new document with `tikz`, but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to create and use this shape in `tikz` (that is: **inside a** `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}` **block**)? How?

Comment: Just `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) to[sinusoidal voltage source, o-o] (3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Bobyandbob Sorry, maybe my question was not clear enough. I don't want to use it in a `circuitikz` block, but in a `tikz` block. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Ah. Then your problem should be solved with [use circuitikz picture inside tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223664/124842) or [Circuitikz symbols in TikZ circuit library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46066/124842).

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thank you, it works. If you want to write an answer, I'll choose it.

Comment: Which link solved your problem? I will flag this as an duplicat.

Comment: @Bobyandbob The [second one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46066/124842).

Answer (score 0):

Using command as "sV"

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
        \draw (0,0) to [sV, l={$v$}, i^>={$i$}](0,3) to (3,3) to [R, l={$R$}](3,0) to (0,0);

    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was not clear enough. I don't want to use it in a `circuitikz` block, but in a `tikz` block. I just edited the question to make it more clear.